# How to use AutoFilter Method in VBA?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to create a macro where a column is filtred based on names. I've created a variable (Cste) which stores the names separated by commas. Yet, when I concatenate it with the other components like so:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:K" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(Cste & "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Everything is deselected.

How do I fix it by selecting only the names stored in Cste ?

Thank you.

Here's the entire code:

```
Sub listeDoublonsPlage()
    Dim Plage As Range
    Dim Tableau() As Variant
    Dim Resultat() As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, m As Integer
    Dim Un As Collection
    Dim Doublons As String
    Dim tablNomtrouves(10000) As String
    Set Un = New Collection


    Sheets("En cours").Select
    lrow = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Plage = Range("C1:C" & lrow)


    Tableau = Range("C1:C5000").Value

    On Error Resume Next
    'boucle sur la plage à tester
    For i = 1 To Plage.Count

        ReDim Preserve Resultat(2, m + 1)

        'Utilise une collection pour rechercher les doublons
        '(les collections n'acceptent que des données uniques)
        Un.Add Tableau(i, 1), CStr(Tableau(i, 1))

        'S'il y a une erreur (donc présence d'un doublon)
        If Err <> 0 Then


            For j = 0 To m + 1
                'Si oui, on  incrémente le compteur
                If Resultat(1, j) = Tableau(i, 1) Then
                    Resultat(2, j) = Resultat(2, j) + 1
                    Err.Clear
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j

                'Si non, on ajoute le doublon dans le tableau
                If Err <> 0 Then
                    Resultat(1, m + 1) = Tableau(i, 1)
                    Resultat(2, m + 1) = 1
                    m = m + 1
                    tablNomtrouves(j) = Tableau(i, 1)
                    Err.Clear

                End If
        End If
    Next i

    '----- Affiche la liste et le nombre de doublons --------
    Dim Cste As String
    Index = 1
    tablSirhus = Array("Olga tintin")
    For j = 0 To UBound(tablSirhus)

        Doublons = Doublons & Resultat(1, j) & " --> " & _
                    Resultat(2, j) & vbCrLf
        'MsgBox ("" & tablNomtrouves(j))

    For y = 0 To UBound(tablNomtrouves)
        payday = allIn(LCase(tablSirhus(j)), LCase(tablNomtrouves(y)))

        If payday = True And Len(Trim(tablNomtrouves(y))) <> 0 Then

            MsgBox ("" & tablNomtrouves(y))
            Cste = Cste & """"
            Cste = Cste & " " & tablNomtrouves(y) & ""
            Cste = Cste & """" & ","
            Index = Index + 1
        End If



    Next y
    Next j

    For i = 0 To Index


    Next i

    Set Un = Nothing

    Cste = Left(Cste, Len(Cste) - 0)
    MsgBox Cste


    Sheets("En cours - MER - Evo").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:K" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(Cste & "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you have, and what you're trying to do, but I would suggest you record a macro with the Macro Recorder, do whatever actions you want to automate, and then check out the VBA code that Excel has generated for you. Also see "[ask]" as well as tips [**here**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and also here are tips about how to create a *[mcve]*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array(Cste & "=")` actually returns a one-element array consisting of your comma separated string, with `=` appended to your string, not an array consisting of multiple elements, where each element is a name. So you'll need to use the Split funtion to convert your comma separated string into an array.

First, start by assigning an empty string ("") to Cste before your For/Next loops...

```
Cste = ""
```

This ensures that we start we an empty string.  Then replace...

```
Cste = Cste & """"
Cste = Cste & " " & tablNomtrouves(y) & ""
Cste = Cste & """" & ",
```

with

```
Cste = Cste & "," & tablNomtrouves(y)
```

Then, if you want to include blanks...

```
Cste = Cste & ",="
```

And, lastly, to remove the first comma from the string...

```
Cste = Mid(Cste, 2)
```

Now `Cste` should be assigned a string such as...

```
quentin coldwater,alice quinn,=
```

And now you can use the Split function to return an array...

```
Criteria1:=Split(Cste, ",")
```

Comment: It's likely because of the way you are building the string being assigned to Cste.  How are your names listed in the worksheet?

Comment: Cste is filled like so : "quentin coldwater", "alice quinn"  How do you think I should modify it in order to work? Thanks

Comment: Actually, it looks `Cste` results in each name not only being wrapped within quotes but preceeded by a space.  And, the comma at the end of the string isn't being removed.  So `Cste` gets assigned `" quentin coldwater", " alice quinn",` .  How do the names actually appear in your worksheet?  With or without quotes?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the worksheet, they don't appear surrounded with quotes, that's true. I added <<<Cste = Left(Cste, Len(Cste) - 1)>>> at the end for the last comma. I tried deleting the quotes and the last comma but it still didn't work...

Comment: Just to be clear, were you able to make the necessary changes, other than the one dealing with the comma at the end?  Or do you still need help with amending the code?

Comment: What I did was just to do that <<<<Cste = " " & Cste & tablNomtrouves(y) & " ,">>>>>>>

Comment: but yes, i still need help. Thank you